# Caught TypeError while rendering: 'BoundField' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to display a list of tags as the tag.name (instead of the list). However when I try and run a for-loop over the list, it throws the **"Caught TypeError while rendering: 'BoundField' object is not iterable."**

```
  <dd>{% for tag in form.tags %}{{tag.name}}{% endfor %}</dd>
```

Iterating through .all will load the page, but doesn't show the Tags field.

```
  <dd>{% for tag in form.tags.all %}{{tag.name}}{% endfor %}</dd>



  class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

  tagging.register(Profile)




form = ProfileForm(initial={
        "fullname":fullname,
        "location":request.user.get_profile().location,
        "website":request.user.get_profile().website,
        "twitter_account":request.user.get_profile().twitter_account,
        "email":request.user.email,
        "bio":request.user.get_profile().bio,
        "tags":request.user.get_profile().tags
    })



    class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
        fullname = forms.CharField(
             label=_("Full Name"),
             widget=forms.TextInput(),
                            required=False)

        location = forms.CharField(
             label=_("Location"),
             widget=forms.TextInput(),
                            required=False)

        website = forms.CharField(
             label=_("Website"),
             widget=forms.TextInput(),
                            required=False)

        twitter_account = forms.CharField(
             label=_("Twitter"),
             widget=forms.TextInput(),
                            required=False)

        bio = forms.CharField(
             label=_("Bio"),
             widget=forms.Textarea(),
                            required=False)

        tags = forms.CharField(
    label=_("Keywords"),
    widget=forms.Textarea(),
                            required=False)
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried loading up the ProfileForm in the django shell and just having a look at what `form.tags.all()` returns?

Comment: I haven't. I'm not very experienced with the django shell. So from forms import ProfileForm ... then?

Comment: `from forms import ProfileForm` then `form = ProfileForm(initial={blahblahblah...})` then `form.tags.all()` and see what it outputs

Comment: >>> form = ProfileForm(initial={'fullname': 'emile', 'tags': {'shoe','cheese'}}) 
>>> form.tags.all()Traceback (most recent call last):  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ProfileForm' object has no attribute 'tags'

Comment: Also one last piece I forgot, is I'm using the Django-Tagging application : http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/

Comment: Updated with my Model too- including the line where I add tagging to the Profile model

Answer (score 1):

Code from a [Howto Post](http://theironlion.net/archive/simple-django-tagging-howto/)

---

Template:

```
{% for tag in blogpost.get_tags %}
  <a href="/blog/tag/{{tag}}" alt="{{tag}}" title="{{tag}}">{{tag}}</a>
{%endfor%}
```

---

Model:

```
from django.db import models
from tagging.fields import TagField
from tagging.models import Tag

class BlogPost(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags = TagField()

    def set_tags(self, tags):
        Tag.objects.update_tags(self, tags)

    def get_tags(self, tags):
        return Tag.objects.get_for_object(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for tag in form.tags.choices %}{{tag.1}}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That actually renders the same way as the .all & {{tag.name}} : https://skitch.com/emilepetrone/d99eq/mentor77

Answer (score 0):

`form.tags` is defined in your form as a `CharField` with a `TextArea` widget. So when you access `form.tags` you are accessing that field, not the underlying `tags` model attribute (which I assume is some sort of m2m).

Without seeing your models it's impossible to tell you exactly how to achieve what you're trying to do, but the general idea is that you need to iterate over the tag objects, not the form field.

Comment: This is using the django-tagging app so thats probably the piece that would help- http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/